# Convert ArrayList<ArrayList<E>> to E[][] in Java

Tags: java

Can you please advice how to convert ArrayList of ArrayLists to simple 2d array in Java in the best way? E.g. I have

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = ...;
```

and want to obrain:

```
String[][] converted = ?;
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
    String[][] converted = new String[data.size()][];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        converted[i] = data.get(i).toArray(new String[data.get(i).size()]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing that comes to mind would be (assuming all second-dimension ArrayLists are the same size):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = ...;
String[][] converted = new String[data.size()][data.get(0).size()];
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    converted[i] = data.get(i).toArray(new String[data.get(i).size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Loop through the content of data, then invoke data.get(someIndex).toArray() and assign that to converted[someIndex]

Answer (score 1):

```
String[][] converted = new String[data.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    converted[i] = data.get(i).toArray(new String[0]);
}
```